# Thailand MO problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

Find all pairs of positive integers (,) satisfying the equation

$m!+n!=m^n+1$

Here’s my try…

By taking mod $m$ we get

$n! \equiv 1 \mod m$.

So we know that $m>n$ (if $m\leq n$ then $m \mid n!$)

then $n \mid m!$

Taking mod $n$ we get

$m^{n}  \equiv -1 \mod n$

let $o$ be the order of $m$ modulo $n$.

Then  $o \mid 2n$ but $o \nmid n$.

And I have no idea what I should do next.

Comment: Please take a quick look at [our policy on contest questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16774/11619). They are generally welcome (assuming they follow the general guidelines), but the special concern is that questions from contests that are currently running are not welcome.

Comment: There is the obvious solution $m=5,n=3$ (possibly other smaller ones, but for some reason this was the first I spotted). To get a rough idea of what the relation between $m$ and $n$ must be I would next estimate both sides by looking at the logarithms. $m$ is bigger, so $m!$ dominates the left , and its logarithm is roughly $m\ln m-m$. On the right the logarithm is essentially $n\ln m$. So we see that $n\approx m-m/\ln m$. Ok, I don't feel particularly enlightened by that :-)

Comment: The obvious solution is 1 1, then 2 1.

Comment: It seems to be very rare for  $m^n+1$ to be divisible with $n!$ when $n>3$. There are solutions other than $m\equiv-1\pmod{n!}$ when $n=9$, but those are too large. This may be a possible line of attack.

Comment: great question! What is Thailand MO?

Comment: MO means "math olympiad".

Comment: It is Thailand October Camp 2019

Answer (score 4):

You have the right general idea in your first part. However, with the equation

$$m!+n!=m^n+1 \; \; \to \; \; n!\left(\frac{m!}{n!}+1\right) = m^n + 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

a small issue is that if $m = 1$, then $n! = 1 \; \to \; n = 1$, so your conclusion of $m \gt n$ should more generally be $m \ge n$ instead. Nonetheless, this still means $\frac{m!}{n!}$ in the RHS above is always an integer.

Consider the results for each integer value of $n \ge 1$. First, with $n = 1$, \eqref{eq1A} becomes $m! + 1 = m + 1 \; \to \; m! = m$, with solutions $m = 1$ and $m = 2$, as [Suzu Hirose's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4536604/thailand-mo-problem#comment9536550_4536604) already indicated.

Next, with $n = 2$, \eqref{eq1A} becomes $m! + 2 = m^2 + 1 \; \to \; 1 = m(m - (m-1)!)$, which has no solutions.

With $n \ge 3$, note \eqref{eq1A} shows $3 \mid m^n + 1$, so $n$ must be odd (since $m^n \equiv 0, 1 \pmod{3}$ for $n$ even). Using the [Lifting-the-exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma) (LTE lemma), we get

$$\nu_2(m^n + 1) = \nu_2(m^n - (-1)^n) = \nu_2(m - (-1)) = \nu_2(m + 1) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Also, since $m \equiv 2 \pmod{3} \; \to \; 3 \mid m + 1$, the LTE lemma gives here that

$$\nu_3(m^n + 1) = \nu_3(m + 1) + \nu_3(n) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Thus, for $n = 3$, \eqref{eq3A} shows that $\nu_3(m^n + 1) \ge 2$. Since $m+1$ is even and is a multiple of $3$, it's a multiple of $6$. However, since $\nu_3(3!) = 1$, then $\nu_3\left(\frac{m!}{n!}+1\right) \ge 1$ so $m \lt 6$ (since, otherwise, $3 \mid \frac{m!}{n!}$). Thus, $m = 5$ is the only possible value, with [Jyrki Lahtonen's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4536604/thailand-mo-problem#comment9536549_4536604) indicating this is another solution.

Note for each increase in $n$ by $2$, there's at least one more factor of $2$ in $n!$, so \eqref{eq2A} shows the minimum value of $m$ must basically at least double. For $n = 5$, since $\nu_2(5!) = 3$ and $\nu_3(5!) = 1$, the minimum ratio of $m$ to $n$ is $\frac{2^3(3) - 1}{5} = \frac{23}{5}$ so, for $n \ge 5$, we have

$$\frac{m}{n} \gt 4.5 \; \; \to \; \; n \lt \frac{m}{4.5} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

From the first part of \eqref{eq1A}, we have

$$m! \lt m^n \; \; \to \; \; \ln(m!) \lt n\ln(m) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) lower bound for $m \ge 1$, and removing a few factors, gives

$$\left(\frac{m}{e}\right)^{m} \lt \sqrt{2\pi m}\left(\frac{m}{e}\right)^{m}e^{\frac{1}{12m+1}} \lt m! \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Next, taking the natural log of \eqref{eq6A} and using \eqref{eq5A} gives

$$m\ln(m) - m \lt n\ln(m) \; \; \to \; \; (m - n)\ln(m) \lt m \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

From \eqref{eq4A}, we have $m - n \gt 0.7(m)$, and $m \ge 23 \; \to \; \ln(m) \gt 3.1$, so the LHS of the second part of \eqref{eq7A} is greater than $3.1(0.7)m = (2.17)m$. However, this contradicts the RHS, so there are no solutions for any $n \ge 5$.

Thus, in summary, the solutions are just $(m,n) \in \{(1,1), (2,1), (5,3)\}$.

Comment: This is great work but it raises doubts about whether this was actually a contest problem, since the above reasoning is not something one would expect to produce as part of a time-limited contest.